# How can I control the language displayed in the Paypal Sandbox?

Tags: localization, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm testing my website payment solution with Paypal Express Checkout, but whenever the customer is taken to the PayPal payment page (in the paypal sandbox), the page displays in English.  How can I control what language is displayed?

On my website I have a language selector and so I do have access to the ISO code of the current language being used on my site.

Comment: Which PayPal product are you using? Website Payments Standard? Express Checkout? Adaptive Payments? Payflow Link?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but I think it is Express Checkout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Express Checkout, you will want to set the `LOCALECODE` to a *four-character country code* supported by PayPal in order to change the language on the PayPal login page.

**Example**

```
CURRENCYCODE=EUR&
RETURNURL=https://www.anycompany.com/orderprocessing/orderreview.html&
CANCELURL=https://www.anycompany.com/orderprocessing/shippinginfo.html&
LOCALECODE=fr_FR
```

- [Changing the Language on the PayPal Login Page](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/expresscheckout.html)
- [SetExpressCheckout Request Parameters](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/Appx_fieldreference.html#2829277)

---

#### EDITED - 2012-05-26

The Paypal Country codes as been updated to 5-character <sup>**(SetExpressCheckout)**</sup>:

*The following 5-character codes are also supported for languages in specific countries*:

- da_DK – Danish (for Denmark only)
- he_IL – Hebrew (all)
- id_ID – Indonesian (for Indonesia only)
- jp_JP – Japanese (for Japan only)
- no_NO – Norwegian (for Norway only)
- pt_BR – Brazilian Portuguese (for Portugal and Brazil only)
- ru_RU – Russian (for Lithuania, Latvia, and Ukraine only)
- sv_SE – Swedish (for Sweden only)
- th_TH – Thai (for Thailand only)
- tr_TR – Turkish (for Turkey only)
- zh_CN – Simplified Chinese (for China only)
- zh_HK – Traditional Chinese (for Hong Kong only)
- zh_TW – Traditional Chinese (for Taiwan only)

See [this link](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout) for updated information on the subject!

Comment: This has actually been changed to 4-character codes a while ago; e.g. en_US, fr_FR, de_DE, et cetera. See also the example in Table 3.9 on https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/expresscheckout.html -- the values in Table A.10 are outdated.

Comment: @Robert Thanks. Originally, the `LOCALECODE` was set to what you edited to, but when I reviewed Table A. 10, I suspected it to be a typo.

Comment: Thanks Josh and Robert.  For reference, a list of language codes can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @justinl, that's *a* list of language codes, not *the* list of supported language codes by PayPal (a very different thing altogether).

Comment: Thanks Robert. Where is the list for paypal?

Comment: I believe this is the link to the Paypal list of language codes: https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/countrycodes_new.html#1006794

Comment: @Josh, updated your answer with the country codes currently being used as **5-character** specification! _(had to deal with this today...)_ and +'d for giving me a starting point :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation from PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) on `SetExpressCheckout`, one should be able to set the `LOCALECODE` to a 5 character locale code, for example `da_DK`. However, I simply couldn't make it work. No matter what 5 character locale code I tried (And I only tried the ones in the PayPal documentation of course), the PayPal UI defaulted to english. But the 2 character locale codes worked.
The solution is not to use the 5 character locales as specified in the documentation, but instead use the 2 character locales mentioned [here](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/countrycodes_new.html#1006794). When I did that, it worked.