# Paypal REST api - How to control the display language?

Tags: php, paypal, localization

I'm working on the PayPal REST API with the official PHP SDK: https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php

However I notice the REST call point me to a check out page (Sandbox mode) in Chinese locale, any idea how to control the display language as English?

I found the same question is asked a year before but no answer: [REST Api integration - how to force payment page's language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323898/rest-api-integration-how-to-force-payment-pages-language)

Or either solution are provided base on Classic API, looks like not applicable on REST API:
[How can I control the language displayed in the Paypal Sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723419/how-can-i-control-the-language-displayed-in-the-paypal-sandbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no `LOCALE` options you can pass to the REST API, however, if you set the shipping address for the transaction it should update automatically. You can test with the call below.

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}' \
-d '{
  "intent":"sale",
  "redirect_urls":{
    "return_url":"http://localhost",
    "cancel_url":"http://localhost"
  },
  "payer":{
    "payment_method":"paypal"
  },
  "transactions":[
    {
        "amount":{
            "total":"7.47",
            "currency":"USD"
        },
        "item_list":{
            "shipping_address":{
                "recipient_name":"Test Test",
                "type":"business",
                "line1":"187 Alameda Santos",
                "city":"Sao Paulo",
                "country_code":"BR",
                "postal_code":"01119",
                "state":"Condominio Edificio Platinum"
            }
        },
        "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
    }
  ]
}'
```

Comment: Your solution works perfect to me! many thanks! BTW I just checked REST API only support direct credit card payment (I suppose it means the typing in CC info for payment when its redirected to Paypal..) with US and UK....will you know about this too :)? I found my Hong Kong credit card passed in Sandbox mode, maybe just sandbox mode..

Comment: This is great indeed, but what if you don't have a shipping address? Like in case of a digital product?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Aaron answer, you can use ExpressCheckout REST api to set a LOCALE see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But then your link pointed to Classic API instead and I didn't search LOCALE for REST api, do you mind provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass locale parameter using the **PayPal** REST APIS as mentioned here -
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/

Example

```
"application_context":{
    "locale":"en_IN",
    "brand_name":"MY BRAND",
    "landing_page":"Billing"
}
```